# conditional probability is not displaying properly in facet label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display the expression p(\theta|y) in a facet label but it displays as p(|(\theta, y))
I have the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

X = seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
prior = dbeta(X, 3, 2)
posterior = dbeta(X, 14, 6)

plot_df =
  tibble(X = X, `p(theta)` = prior, `p(theta|y)` = posterior) %>%
  gather(type, Y, -X) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("p(theta)", "p(theta|y)")))

ggplot(plot_df, aes(X, Y)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, labeller = label_parsed, strip.position = "left") +
  xlab(expr(theta)) +
  ylab("")
```

[image: output]

So how do I get that to display as p(\theta | y)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works. The trick is to add spacing characters, asterisks, and to put the vertical bar between single quotes. This must match the new factor levels.

```
plot_df =
  tibble(X = X, `p(theta)` = prior, `p(theta*'|'*y)` = posterior) %>%
  gather(type, Y, -X) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("p(theta)", "p(theta*'|'*y)")))
```

The rest of the code is exactly the same.

```
ggplot(plot_df, aes(X, Y)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, labeller = label_parsed, strip.position = "left") +
  xlab(expr(theta)) +
  ylab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this does work. Is there a reference somewhere for all of this? Because quite frankly mathematical expressions in ggplot2 confuse the crap out of me. I wouldn't have figured this answer out in a hundred years.

Comment: @OldMcFartigan The main reference is `help('plotmath')`. Plus R-Help, SO, etc. And trial and error, lots of it. In this case my first try was without the single quotes. When the error message pointed at the vertical bars I got it right.